# Python - make request with SSL certificate stored in Windows certificate Store

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I'm googling second day in a row and still can't get a solution that works for me. I need to make a request using client certificate that is stored in Windows Certificate Store on path "\Personal\Certificates\my-cert". I need to supply this certificate to `request.post()`. I think I've tried everything I could including `cert=certifi.where()` or `verify=True` but still no luck. I've even tried `urllib.request.urlopen(url + endpoint, cafile=certifi.where())` but I always get some kind of SSL error. I'm unable to provide any code snippet since I've tried like 20 things and none of them work. So my question is - how to make a POST request with client certificate? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is a way to use the certificate directly from Windows certificate store, i.e. you would need to export cert and key as PEM and then use it [as documented](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#client-side-certificates). Apart from that none what you've tried (at least what you've shown) has anything to do with sending client certificate to the server - it is only about validating server certificate.